# angular material Datepicker -Cannot access 'SatCalendar' before initialization

Tags: angular, angular-material

I got this error when I try to run my angular application:

```
   ./node_modules/saturn-datepicker/fesm2015/saturn-datepicker.js @ saturn-datepicker.js:1765
 __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79 ./src/app/app.module.ts @ app.component.ts:8
 __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79 ./src/main.ts @ environment.ts:16
 __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79 0 @ main.ts:13
 __webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:79 checkDeferredModules @ bootstrap:45 webpackJsonpCallback @ bootstrap:32 (anonymous) @ main.js:1 client:52
 [WDS] Live Reloading enabled.
```

In my application I have angular v8, material, momentjs.

What I need to do to fix this error?

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    **"@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^8.2.3",**
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.9",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "saturn-datepicker": "^8.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0"
```

*component.html*

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>start your vacation at</mat-label>
    <input matInput [matDatepicker]="dp" [formControl]="startDate" />
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="dp"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-datepicker #dp></mat-datepicker>
  </mat-form-field>
```

*component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import {
  MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS,
  MomentDateAdapter
} from "@angular/material-moment-adapter";
import {
  DateAdapter,
  MAT_DATE_FORMATS,
  MAT_DATE_LOCALE
} from "@angular/material/core";
// import { _rollupMoment } from "moment";
import * as _moment from "moment";

const moment = _moment;

@Component({
  selector: "app-order",
  templateUrl: "./order.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./order.component.css"],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: DateAdapter,
      useClass: MomentDateAdapter,
      deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]
    },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: MAT_MOMENT_DATE_FORMATS }
  ]
})
export class OrderComponent implements OnInit {
  startDate = new Date(2019, 0, 1);
  constructor() {}
  form = new FormGroup({
    customeLastName: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    customeFirstName: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
    startDate: new FormControl(moment([2020, 3, 1]))
  });

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem .
its because Material range datepicker  has been deprecated.
and can`t use this npm package anymore 
[npm Material range datepicker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/saturn-datepicker)

its work fine now without the package, after remove it from the package.json

```
 "saturn-datepicker": "^8.0.2",
```